# List text between two regex functions

Tags: java, regex

hello everyone i wanted to get a text between two regex functions my log file is

```
11:40:04,202 [ERROR] JobStoreTX - Failed to close Connection
 java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.closeConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3579)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanupConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3555)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3783)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2728)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
11:40:04,202 [ERROR] QuartzSchedulerThread - quartzSchedulerThreadLoop: RuntimeException null
 java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy1.rollback(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.rollbackConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3604)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3773)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2728)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:71)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: 
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:1132)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:368)
    at `enter code here`org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.rollback(PoolingDataSource.java:323)
    ... 10 more
11:41:47,203 [ERROR] JobStoreTX - Failed to close Connection
```

i want text between two timestamp ie. 11:40:04,202 and 11:40:04,202 which should contain this....

```
11:40:04,202 [ERROR] JobStoreTX - Failed to close Connection
 java.sql.SQLException: Already closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:191)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.closeConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3579)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanupConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3555)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3783)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2728)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:264)
```

kk let me make it more simple....

```
static String str1 = "09:37:58,289 This is my small 09:39:18,129 example string which I'm going" +
                             " to use for pattern matching 09:38:15,835 This is my small example string which" +
                             " I'm going to use for pattern matching";

        String patrn = "((\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+),(\\d+))";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patrn);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str1);



        /*while(m.find())
        {
            for(int i=1;i<m.groupCount();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i);

                System.out.println(m.group(i));
                start = m.start();
                System.out.println(start);
                end = m.end();
                System.out.println(end);

                i+=3;
            }
        }*/



        The output which i needed is.....
        String1 = 09:37:58,289 This is my small 
        String2 = 09:39:18,129 example string which I'm going to use for pattern matching
        String3 = 09:38:15,835 This is my small example string which I'm going to use for pattern matching
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract the error message?

Comment: Do you mean to say, "List text in log file that is LOGGED between calls to two functions "

Comment: @Dibya yes...need to extract text within two timestamp using regex

Comment: @Sumeet: Can you please explain what you are trying to acheive, you may consider the option of changing the Log4jPattern.

Comment: @Dibya i have a server log file(text file) and i want break it in to u can say parts i have shown above a snap of log file and i want break this in to output as i shown...

Comment: so every part should start with its timestamp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print only the stacktrace not the date and Log level then you may consider creating your own patter.

Java Doc for [log4j pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)